Check if file exists and is in @INC to require
I'm writing a script that will take input from user in order to load a configuration/data file.
My first though was (assume the file name is in $file):
if (-e $file) {
    my $data = do $file;
    die "Failed to parse data\n" if $@;
} else {
    die "File does not exist\n";
}

This works to a certain extent — if the file does not exist it dies accordingly. However, if it does, and is not a full path (beginning with /) and instead is relative to current directory, it dies with a message coming from Perl:

[…] '.' is no longer in @INC; did you mean do […]

Why is that? I don't want to add . to @INC, but I'm surprised that this didn't die with my message instead. Shouldn't it just fail the do and set $@?
How can I test that a file exists and is in reach of @INC? Or, maybe another solution, like reliably testing for the path in the current directory and making it a full path before passing to do.

You really shouldn't save configuration data as Perl code. /// And why would you want configuration data saved in a Perl module directory??

@ikegami It seems to be rather common, from what I use, to store a config hash as perl code. A file with a single hash, and with all of Perl code flexibility. You said I shouldn't. Why? Also, note I never said it is in a module directory.

You're already running into issues -- issues you can't resolve by yourself even -- and you ask why???

Re "note I never said it is in a module directory.", uh, you said you used require. you actually used do, but that applies as well. Both search for modules in module directories.

@ikegami the issue clearly is how to locate and read the file reliably, considering it's path comes from user input. Not the config format itself. As for require/do, I apologize for that: initially I wrote require mistakenly on the question, since I was playing with both in my script.

Re "the issue clearly is how to locate and read the file reliably", I don't know why are you telling me that given that I answered this question???

Your code does not produce the message you say it does, but do EXPR can produce that warning.
$ touch foo   # The file must exist for the warning to be produced.

$ perl -e'do "foo"'
do "foo" failed, '.' is no longer in @INC; did you mean do "./foo"? at -e line 1.

You can silence the warning using
no warnings qw( deprecated );

The reason it warns is because it used to "work" (as long as the current work directory happened to be the script's directory), but a change to Perl caused it to stop working.
do only sets $@ if there's an exceptions from the compilation/execution of the file. Inability to access the file only sets $!.

Don't use code as configuration. Use a common format like JSON, YAML, TOML, INI, or whatever. There are plenty of modules that can handle any of those. I have an entire chapter on this in Mastering Perl.
As for your question, Perl removed the current working directory from the default module search path in v5.26 so people can't drop their own module in the current directory and trick your program into executing unexpected and possibly malicious code. That's what you're trying to re-allow.

Thank you. I certainly know about . having been removed, and even mentioned in the question I don't want to add it back. The problem is maybe that I did not word my question properly: I wanted to know how to test if the given path (by the user) is reachable to do or any way to ensure it will be converted to a full path which is safe to do. @ikegami answered one of the side-questions: what I see is a warning, and I could check $! instead. As for using other format, that's not the question. I see in SO questions need to be objective but answers not. I did not ask for a opinion on that.

I must add that I'm surprised with comments on the config/data format itself, as it is not part of the question. At the same time, as usual, the answer was in the Perl manual for do. By the way, who would say, eh… the Perl manual mentions you might like to use do to read in a program configuration file. So, the real answer to my question might be simply to always convert any user given path to a full path and then test and do. That removes the dependency on @INC. And there are plenty of modules to work with that path handling.

If you didn't want anyone to address the actual task, don't put it in the first sentence. :) But it sounds like an XY problem. But, these answers are not for just you. They are for anyone who comes later and should be warned that do is not the solution they want, and that arbitrary code as configuration is a security issue.
